# How to disable prestashop's page-not-found redirect?

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-404, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a Prestashop 1.6 installed on a VPS hosting and all is working well with it, except that when I try to reach a page that doesn't exist, instead of serving the 404 page of the template, a 301 redirect is returned and the client is redirected to `index.php?controller=page-not-found` where the 404 template is shown.

This is not working for me due to SEO reasons.
How do I disable this redirect?

Thanks

Comment: usually these changes occur in Class/controllers/frontControllers.php or controllers/front/PageNotFoundController.php.
These files have been changed or have override ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the default behavior of prestashop is to redirect. It was not a override. Anyway - I found a way to achieve what I wanted to do anyway.

After some time struggling with that - I came up with a retarded solution, that will do for now.
I am sharing it here, because I sure would have appreciated finding it few days ago, but be warned - it is retarded to the point of no return.
Not recommended if you can come up with something else.

What I did was this - I found the CategoryController.php file in the controllers/front/ folder.
There should  be this row:

```
if (!$this->category->active)
```

In it I make a php file_get_contents request to the 404.html page of the website, and serve it.
Afterwards I terminate the php script with an exit(); command.

This way the server sends out the 404.html content, without redirecting.
Here is the full code:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
header('Status: 404 Not Found');

echo file_get_contents('https://website.com/404/'
false,
stream_context_create(
array(
'http' => array(
'ignore_errors' => true
)
)
)
);
exit();
```

Don't forget that if the controller is overridden it might not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in overrided Tools controller

public static function redirectLink($url)
  {

```
 $init_url=$url;

  if (!preg_match('@^https?://@i', $url)) {
      if (strpos($url, __PS_BASE_URI__) !== false && strpos($url, __PS_BASE_URI__) == 0) {
          $url = substr($url, strlen(__PS_BASE_URI__));
      }
      if (strpos($url, 'index.php?controller=') !== false && strpos($url, 'index.php/') == 0) {
          $url = substr($url, strlen('index.php?controller='));
      }
      $explode = explode('?', $url);
      $url = Context::getContext()->link->getPageLink($explode[0]);
      if (isset($explode[1])) {
          $url .= '?'.$explode[1];
      }
  }


if ((string)trim($init_url)==='404') {
      header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");

      header('Status: 404 Not Found');
      echo file_get_contents($url, false,
            stream_context_create(
              array('http' =>  array('ignore_errors' => true,
                               ),
              )
            )
          );

      exit();
    } else {

            header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved");
            header('Location: '.$url);
            exit();

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A global solution for this (so you don't have to go controller by controller) is going straight to the -> classes/Dispatcher.php
In there you will find the dispatch function.
You can do something like ->

```
if ($this->controller == $this->controller_not_found) {
//your code here
}
```

before the line where the controller is going to be executed

```
$controller->run();
```